# how can i configure the service provider in wso2is for different tenants of version 5.2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

As per the documentation, enabling the SAAS Application, allows the Service provider to all tenants is not working.Even Though we have created the service provider per each tenant.
when login by using wso2is authentication page it is saying authentication fails.
I have seen the log file of WSO2IS it says service provider has to be registered. 
But,we have tested the same service provider application name  by using the soap webservice by  giving the same credentials it is giving the response.

```
   Thanks In advance,
```

Comment: In what tenant you created the service provider? Is it in super tenant or in a tenant you created later.

Comment: Thank  you for reply pulasthi,In the super tenant we have created the service provider and the tenant created later we have service provider and for the service provider we have enabled the SASS.

Comment: @pulasthi7 same issue here, when using getServiceProviders() WS with different tenant doesn't yield the SP app name in the Soap response, even after configuring the super.tenant SP app as SaaS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is,

1. Verify the ClientId/ClientSecret is associated with the Application/SP.
2. If Using SoapWS, for OAuthServices then use the super-user credentials(~assuming the clientID/clientSecret belongs to superUser).

If using HTTP-Post:Binding, replace the secToken, respective to each user(~this is for validation in SAMLsoo/SAMLAssertion).
Hope it helps..!

Comment: ,Yes it has clarified ,Thanku